# El Capitan: will System Integrity Protection defence stop sandbox program from accessing System.log?

Tags: macos, security

OS X El Capitan apparently has this new security feature known as `System Integrity Protection`, which limits root access to an array of files including: `/system`, `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr`, `/etc`, `/tmp` and `/var`.

I have a program I developed which accesses the file `system.log` located in the /var/log/ directory.

My Question is:

- **Will my program (running in the sandbox) be able to access the file /var/log/system.log with the 'System Integrity Protection' system running?**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will my program (running in the sandbox) be able to access the file `/var/log/system.log` with the 'System Integrity Protection' system running?

Yes, a sandboxed application will be able to access `/var/log/system.log` on OS X with [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) (SIP) enabled.

### `/var` is Not Protected

The `/var` folder is not protected by SIP. As of OS X 10.11, only [the following locations are protected](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899):

> Paths and applications protected by System Integrity Protection include:
>
> - `/System`
> - `/usr`
> - `/bin`
> - `/sbin`
> - Apps that are pre-installed with OS X
>
> Paths and applications that third-party apps and installers can write to include:
>
> - `/Applications`
> - `/Library`
> - `/usr/local`

See Apple's [developer documentation on System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more details.